# I want to draw a map of Korea in highchart, including Dokdo. What should I do?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, highcharts

I am developing a map of Korea using highchart.

However, it is difficult to proceed with the project because Dokdo is not marked on the map of Korea provided by highchart.

How can I develop a map **including Dokdo** using highchart?

Jsfiddle URL: https://jsfiddle.net/jsill2786/bsguoxhq/

```
(async () => {

const topology = await fetch(
    'https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/kr/kr-all.topo.json'
).then(response => response.json());

// Prepare demo data. The data is joined to map using value of 'hc-key'
// property by default. See API docs for 'joinBy' for more info on linking
// data and map.
const data = [
    ['kr-4194', 10], ['kr-kg', 11], ['kr-cb', 12], ['kr-kn', 13],
    ['kr-2685', 14], ['kr-pu', 15], ['kr-2688', 16], ['kr-sj', 17],
    ['kr-tj', 18], ['kr-ul', 19], ['kr-in', 20], ['kr-kw', 21],
    ['kr-gn', 22], ['kr-cj', 23], ['kr-gb', 24], ['kr-so', 25],
    ['kr-tg', 26], ['kr-kj', 27]
];

let city_code = ['kr-kg', 'kr-cb', 'kr-so', 'kr-kn', 'kr-2685', 'kr-pu', 
'kr-2688','kr-sj', 'kr-tj', 'kr-ul', 'kr-in', 'kr-kw', 'kr-gn', 'kr-cj', 
'kr-gb', 'kr-tg', 'kr-kj']

let city_name = ['경기도', '전북', '서울', '경상남도', '전라남도', '부산', 
'경상북도', '세종', '대전', '울산', '인천', '강원도', '충청남도', '제주도', '충청북도',
'대구', '광주광역시']

// Create the chart
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    chart: {
        map: topology
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Korea Map'
    },

    subtitle: {
        // text: 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/kr/kr-all.topo.json">South Korea</a>'
    },

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0
    },

    series: [{
        data: data,
        name: 'Random data',
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#BADA55'
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            // format: '{point.name}',
            formatter: function() {
                for (let i = 0; i < city_code.length; i++){
                if (this.point['hc-key'] === city_code[i]){
                    return city_name[i]
                }
                
              }
            
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

})();

[Map without Dokdo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Gf5.png)

[Maps with Dokdo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l3sJ.png)

Comment: Perhaps `highcharts` are not interested in getting involved in disputed rocks

Answer (score 0):

In case there is no map or element on the map in our Highcharts Map collection, you can request it here: https://github.com/highcharts/map-collection-dist/issues

You can also create your own map following the guidelines of the article:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/create-custom-maps

As a workaround, you can consider adding Dokdo as a point:

```
  {
  name: 'North Gyeongsang',
    type: 'mappoint',
    data: [{
      name: 'Dokdo',
      lat: 37.24,
      lon: 131.5,
    }]
  }
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b1xhzmrd/